# Reconstruct javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
"Emergency services":[  
  {  
     "benefit":"Emergency room care",
     "category":"Emergency services",
     "limit":"232323",
     "limit_individual":"232323",
     "max_day_limit":"2332",
     "plan":"newPlan",
     "isChecked":false
  },
  {  
     "benefit":"Ambulance service",
     "category":"Emergency services",
     "limit":"3223",
     "limit_individual":"2323",
     "max_day_limit":"2323",
     "plan":"newPlan",
     "isChecked":true
  },
  {  
     "benefit":"Urgent care centers/facilities",
     "category":"Emergency services",
     "limit":"2323",
     "limit_individual":"2323",
     "max_day_limit":"2323",
     "plan":"newPlan",
     "isChecked":true
  }
],
```

Which I need to reconstruct to

```
{  
     "benefit":"Urgent care centers/facilities",
     "category":"Emergency services",
     "limit":"2323",
     "limit_individual":"2323",
     "max_day_limit":"2323",
     "plan":"newPlan"
  }
```

if `isChecked` value is true.

If `isChecked` value is false I want to discard that whole array object from the array and then send the resulting array to the backend API

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with a simple `for-loop` in JS:

```
var input = [  
  {  
     "benefit":"Emergency room care",
     "category":"Emergency services",
     "limit":"232323",
     "limit_individual":"232323",
     "max_day_limit":"2332",
     "plan":"newPlan",
     "isChecked":false
  },
  {  
     "benefit":"Ambulance service",
     "category":"Emergency services",
     "limit":"3223",
     "limit_individual":"2323",
     "max_day_limit":"2323",
     "plan":"newPlan",
     "isChecked":true
  },
  {  
     "benefit":"Urgent care centers/facilities",
     "category":"Emergency services",
     "limit":"2323",
     "limit_individual":"2323",
     "max_day_limit":"2323",
     "plan":"newPlan",
     "isChecked":true
  }];

  var output = [];

  for (var i=0; i<input.length; i+=1) {
    var item = input[i];

    if (item.isChecked) {
        //delete the isChecked property
        delete item.isChecked;
        //add item to output
        output.push(item);
    }
  }

  console.log(output);
```

**Check it out:** https://jsfiddle.net/ynpu6tv1/